# Contenteditable div returns <br> when empty on IE

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get `innerHTML` of `contenteditable` field, and relying on that decide save it or not.

I have markup like this

```
<div class="users-overlay" contenteditable></div>
```

so when I am using `document.querySelector('.users-overlay').innerHTML` it returns `<br>`. This behaviour appears only on IE/Edge. I need to get rid of this somehow. Because even when I write `document.querySelector('.users-overlay').innerHTML = ''` it is still here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on IE or Edge. My guess is something else not mentioned in your question is adding the tag.

Comment: Why don't you just strip the first "<br>" from the content if there is one at the begining of it?

Comment: i can strip it, but i want to realize why it appears.

Comment: You can't rely on `innerHTML` anyway, the places of the attributes are changing from time to time in IE.

Comment: Forgot to mention, i checked on other sites, ye it is not present. May be because i am using Angular.

Comment: @Edit I verified the OPs issue. If you grab innerHTML of an empty contentEditable div in IE it returns `<br>`. I looked into it a bit and found [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/6492250/) edge bug report that sounds similiar.